# Xamarin Android BulletSpan Radius missing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I wanted to set radius for BulletSpan to make bullet larger then its default appearance. I found the solution on Android with link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BulletSpan but same is not available in Xamarin Android BulletSpan.

Android Link explains about constructor which is not available in Xamarin Android part.

```
public BulletSpan (int gapWidth, 
                int color, 
                int bulletRadius)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `BulletSpan` `.ator` that accepts `gapWidth`, `color`, & `bulletRadius` was added in API level 28 (Android P). Which is currently in preview state from Google.

`Xamarin.Android` just merged support for API 28/P last week:

- [Final P API update. #1790](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/1790)

> Added in API level 28
>
> public BulletSpan (int gapWidth, 
>                   int color, 
>                   int bulletRadius)
>
> Creates a BulletSpan based on a gap width and a color integer.

#### Update:

Xamarin.Android 8.4 (Preview) has been released so if you want to try out the new APIs in this release with an Android P/28 emulator/device you can:

- https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.4/

Comment: Thanks. What library i should update to test this constructor?

Comment: @RaviKanasagra It is not available yet for `Xamarin.Android` and again only on API 28(+), you could use Android Studio with the Android P SDK and an Android P-based emulator (unless you have one of the few Project Treble-based phones that are allowing Android P Beta/Preview to be installed)